# Console log not logging with express and socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm having trouble understanding how web sockets work. I'm not seeing my console.log "connection" inside the io.on function when I visit http://www.localhost:3010 in my browser. Could someone explain why that is?

server.js:

```
const app = require("./backend/app")
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app)
var socketIo = require('socket.io')


server.listen(3010, () => {
    console.log("listening")
})

const io = socketIo(server)


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("connection")
    socket.emit("news", {hello: "world"})
})
```

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("hello world");
})


module.exports = app
```

Comment: Your web page has to initialize a socket connection on the client side.  So you'd have to res.send an HTML page or host a static folder with some HTML and Javascript and initialize socket IO there and then connect to the backend.

Right now you spin up the socketio connection and then never connect to it.

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Looks like you did the first step - but you have to do the other steps to actually get the client to connect.

Comment: What @WakeskaterX said. See the socket.io docs: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Emitting-events